# Rails 4 will_paginate global per_page not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have a small app, where I want to set the 'items per page' for all my listings (**per user**, *each user can customize this value, but for all the system listings*). I'm using will_paginate (https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), as it looks kind of the defacto gem for paging.

When the user logs in, I'm performing:

```
WillPaginate.per_page = <user defined value>
```

The code where I'm using will_paginate is:

```
@expedientes = Expediente.buscar(params).ordenar(@criterio_orden, @area).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

will_paginate is totally ignoring this. The only way in which SOMETIMES it used this value, was logging it before making a DB query. I don't want to specify the items per page in each query.

Has anyone had this problem? Any hint to solve it...?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Debugging will_paginate I've found that when you do

```
WillPaginate.per_page = <user defined value>
```

it calls this method:

```
module WillPaginate
  module PerPage
    ...
    def per_page=(limit)
      @per_page = limit.to_i
    end
```

An instance method setting an instance variable? Is this OK? Should I report it in will_paginate github or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show the `pagination code` from `controlle`r and also show the `view code` where you are using it.

Comment: You can set it in query itself like `:per_page=>10`.Like `@expedientes = Expediente.buscar(params).ordenar(@criterio_orden, @area).paginate(page: params[:page]:per_page=>10,)`.

Comment: That would be a hack. First I want to try to use it as it's supposed to be used.

Comment: What do you mean by 'First I want to try to use it as it's supposed to be used'?

Comment: The will_paginate documentation says: # set per_page globally
WillPaginate.per_page = 10   That means that you CAN set a global value to use in EVERY query. And that's what I want to use.

Comment: Oh,i see.So you have set `WillPaginate.per_page = some_value`.Where did you put that line in your application?

Comment: Currently I'm trying to set it when a user logs in, so the `login` method in my `AdminController`

Comment: Try to put it in the config/application.rb.That only.`WillPaginate.per_page = some_value`

Comment: If I put it there I won't be able to customize the value per user. Check the update I've put to the original post. What do you think of will_paginate code?

Comment: You want to customize the `per_page` value per user?

Comment: If you want to set the page size per user that's a massive omission in the question - I'd seriously consider adding that information. The setting you are using is for a global page size and nothing to do with the scope of a user's request.

Comment: Are you doing this in a before filter or around filter?

Comment: No, only when a user logs in.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this ?

Comment: I've tried using it in a before_action filter and it seems to change it but will_paginate is ignoring it. I've also noticed the before_action filter works in my dev environment but not in production. Hint there, maybe?